# php send get request and get output

Tags: php, curl, get, request

I want to make a getrequest to www.seatguru.com, which for instance would look like this: `http://www.seatguru.com/findseatmap/findseatmap.php?airlinetext=American+Airlines&carrier=AA&flightno=3180&from=Philadelphia%2C+PA+-+Philadelphia+International+Airport+%28PHL%29&to=&date=07%2F03%2F2013&from_loc=PHL&to_loc=&search_type=`

The problem is that when I get the request back, it only shows the 'Loading...', which means that I can check the output. Is there any way I can get around that?

Here's my curl:

```
$qry_str = "?airlinetext=American+Airlines&carrier=AA&flightno=3180&from=Philadelphia%2C+PA+-+Philadelphia+International+Airport+%28PHL%29&to=&date=07%2F03%2F2013&from_loc=PHL&to_loc=&search_type=";
$ch = curl_init();

// Set query data here with the URL
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://www.seatguru.com/findseatmap/findseatmap.php' . $qry_str); 

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, '3');
$content = trim(curl_exec($ch));
curl_close($ch);
```

Thanks alot.

Comment: dont scrape sites that ask you not to.

Comment: Oh I didn't realise it asked me not to. My bad.

Comment: not surprising really, spend millions of dollars on your site, you don't want other's to steal from you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is happening because the results are actually loaded via ajax. So when the page is loaded, the results aren't there and you see the loading sign. You can get around this by querying the url that the page uses to get the results. Ideally, you would search through document inspector(Chrome/FF Firebug) for XHR requests and sort through them for the relevant one, but hey I did the work for you.

```
http://www.seatguru.com/ajax/findseatmap.php?from=PHL&to=&flightno=3180&carrier=AA&date=07%2F03%2F2013
```

(Note the ajax in the url before findseatmap)

Oh and do ask them before you scrape. Its generally bad to scrape since they lose business.

Comment: want to help him rob a bank to?

Comment: Its still a valid question. You can't really expect to keep people from robbing banks by not telling them how the lock turns.

Comment: i agree you cant, but still think its worth trying.

Comment: but there'll always be another guy around. One who won't postscript it with an ethical warning. Okay maybe giving the link was overkill

Comment: @dagon is that not a bit over the top, robbing a bank != scraping a site. And we are not the ethics police! seatguru should improve their security if they are really opposed to this, and who says the asker will not add a link to their site and actually increase their visits... +1 for the right answer.

Comment: I just want to the the flight model from the flight number, maybe I'll just ask American Airlines for an API/XML feed instead.